# How to map a variable value to a specified string?

Tags: c

Suppose that I have associated (in my mind, not as code) a status thing with an integer array of size n. 
`int array[n] = {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,.......}`. (only 0 and 1 in this array)
Status '0' means 'locked' in my context. Similarly, '1' means 'unlocked'.
I want that everytime, I print the variable, e.g. `int array[3]`, I want to output its status as a string and not the actual value of variable.

How do I do this? Is there a way I can actually replace `0` with "locked" and `1` with "unlocked"?
 
P.S. - I DON'T want to create another array with data type string or simply putting an if-else equation. Help with macros will be much appreciated.

Comment: `puts((char *[2]){"locked", "unlocked"}[!!array[3]]);` is a start using a _compound literal_.

Comment: `puts("unlocked" + 2 * !array[3]);`

Comment: `#define show_lock(b) ((b) ? "unlocked" : "locked")` and then output show_lock(array[n]) with `printf()`, `fputs()`, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Are you talking about C strings or C++ strings?  Since they're wholly different, you should only have one of the two language tags on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that an assignment which isn't well understood ?

I think the comment of  Mike Housky is correct. But let me add some more "Macros", perhaps this answer will be downvoted.

```
#define LOCKED 0
#define UNLOCKED 1
#define PRINT(x) (x == LOCKED) ? printf("locked") : printf("unlocked")
```

use as

```
int array[n] = {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,.......}
or 
int array[n] = {LOCKED,UNLOCKED,LOCKED,.......}

PRINT(array[3]);
```

Comment: not an assignment. kind of a part of project. much tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use string literals and decide which to use based on the value of the array slot.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  const char *is_locked = (array[i] == 0) ? "locked" : "unlocked";
  printf("status of %d: %s\n", i, is_locked);
}
```

Comment: will work, no doubt. But in my code, it is unnecessarily conditioned that I need to print that variable (0 or 1). I should not be printing its status. Is there a way I can replace 0 or 1 with locked or unlocked. (MACROS?)

Comment: Yes, you can use a macro.  But the rules describing your constraint are unclear.  " it is unnecessarily conditioned that I need to print that variable (0 or 1)" -- what does this mean?  I can't change the caller, it will call "print_this_val(array[n])"?  You could still always change the definition of `print_this_val`.  So what is the real constraint?

Comment: how he will define macro if he will define `#define 0 "locked"`, won't it replace zeros in condition checking

Comment: why do you insist on macros?